# What is it called when a project is released under several different licenses simultaneously?

Tags: licensing

Sometimes, perhaps due to code's history, a project is released under several different licenses at the same time.  An example of this is [ranges-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/blob/master/LICENSE.txt).  **What is the name for this practise?**

To be clear I'm not asking about [dual-licensing / multi-licensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-licensing), which is when the recipient can choose which of several licenses to follow.  My question is about when the terms of several different licenses must *all* be followed.

Comment: The license you link to isn't saying one thing is released under multiple licenses, it's saying several things are distributed under their respective licenses.

Comment: @curiousdanii That is certainly one way to look at it, but all the constituent parts are released together as a single unit.

Answer (score 4):

The practice you are referring to is "using code written by others that is under a different license". This happens most frequently when you take code from other projects and incorporate that in your codebase.

As mentioned in the readme file of the project:

> Most of the source code in this project are mine, and those are under the Boost Software License. Parts are taken from Alex Stepanov's Elements of Programming, Howard Hinnant's libc++, and from the SGI STL. Please see the attached LICENSE file and the CREDITS file for the licensing and acknowledgments.

Comment: That is a good *description* of what has happened in this case.  Does it have a (shorter) *name*?